# How to generate a three level dependable dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba

I am a complete VBA beginner and this is the first time I have had to deal with VBA. My project is simple- a user form which heavily relies on dependent drop down lists. I watched a ton of videos and wrote (more like copy-pasted) code which actually works just fine. My issue is that I need to edit part of my code to add a feature which I have trouble finding a video on (trial and error editing only took me this far).
In it's current state, my form has two dropdown lists drawing information from a sheet where data is arranged in columns as follows:

ITEM ID | ITEM | CATEGORY

The user picks a category and then the item list if filtered based on the previous selection. I now need to rearrange those columns are add another one, making it the 1st tier selection as follows:

LOCATION | CATEGORY | ITEM ID | ITEM

Just rearranging the columns alone breaks my code. On top of that I need to add the Location combobox, which would filter the Categories, which in turn filter the Items.
This is the code which handles the CATEGORY and ITEM list:

```
Private Sub cmbEquipCategory_Change()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim lastBlankRow As Long

Me.cmbEquipment.Clear

Set sh = Sheets("Equipment_List")
lastBlankRow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastBlankRow
If sh.Cells(i, 3) = Me.cmbEquipCategory.value Then
Me.cmbEquipment.AddItem sh.Cells(i, 2)
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

It is my impression that I need to alter this code to draw data from columns 2 and 4 (it currently does so from 3 and 2) and write another almost identical block of code which handles LOCATION and CATEGORY. Any advice, resources or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this is to used named ranges.  So selecting your ITEM ID would lead to one of several ITEM ranges (I name them according to the ITEM ID options) which would lead to one of several CATEGORY ranges (I name these according to the ITEM options).  The more options you have the more ranges you need. Named ranges aren't broken by adding in columns.